# Prove equation $(ad-bc)(a-c)^2 = (b-d)^3$, if polynomials has common root

Tags: polynomials

> $$\begin{split}
>  W(x) &= x^3 + ax + b \wedge a,b \in \mathbb{R} 
>   &\wedge \mathbb{D}_W &= \mathbb{R}\\
>  G(x) &= x^3 + cx + d \wedge c,d \in \mathbb{R}
>   &\wedge \mathbb{D}_G &= \mathbb{R}
>  \end{split}
>  $$ Prove:
>   $$ \left(\exists p \in \mathbb{R}\right)\left(W(p) = 0 = G(p)\right)
> \Longrightarrow \left((ad-bc)(a-c)^2 = (b-d)^3\right)$$

I cannot prove it. It's obvious if $p = 0$ cause $d=b=0$. But otherwise I don't see solution. How can I prove it?

---

I noticed that $pa+b =cp+d$, so $(b-d) = p(c-a)$. Therefore 
$(b-d)^3 = 
%p^2(c-a)^2(b-d)=
(a-c)^2 \cdot p^2(b-d)$.

Now I just have to show, that $p^2(b-d) = (ad-bc)$.
I tried ($b \neq d)$ show that:
$$ \frac{ad}{b-d} - \frac{bc}{b-d} = p^2$$
From first observation, if $c \neq a$, $p^2 = \left( \frac{b-d}{c-a} \right)^2$, but it's now worthless.I don't see next step. Can you show me, how I should finish that proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y$ be the common root. We then have
$$y^3 + ay+b = 0 \text{ and }y^3+cy+d = 0$$
This means we have
$$ay+b = cy+d \implies y = \frac{d-b}{a-c}$$
Hence,
$$\left(\frac{d-b}{a-c}\right)^3 + a \left(\frac{d-b}{a-c}\right) + b = 0$$
This gives us
$$(d-b)^3 + a(d-b)(a-c)^2 + b(a-c)^3 = 0 \implies (b-d)^3 = (a-c)^2(ad-ab+ba-bc)$$
which simplifies to what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of $p$ in any of the equations, say the first one to get,
$$(b-d)^3=b(a-c)^3-(a-c)^2a(b-d)=(a-c)^2(ab-bc-ab+ad)=(a-c)^2(ad-bc)$$